# Importing with boost python

Tags: python, python-3.x, boost-python

Whether I import like this:

```
numpy_module = bp::import("numpy");
```

or like this:

```
numpy_module = bp::scope().attr("numpy");
```

I get

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::python::error_already_set'
```

I didn't have a problem with Python 2.7, but after upgrading to Python 3.1, this strange exception crops up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it:  I needed to compile Boost for Python31.

Comment: You should accept your own answer here then.  But a word for next time: you should call `PyErr_Print()` when you catch `error_already_set` and it will show you the real error message from Python.

Comment: Cool.  And if you want to propagate the exception as a std::exception you can do that by using PyErr_Fetch() to get the value (string) of the exception, then re-throwing it as a std::exception in C++.  Why Boost Python doesn't seem to come with a helper to do this I don't know.